# Delete Rules with Reflexive Relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, rule

I have an Xcode project with a single Entity in Core Data ("Item") and have set up a reflexive relationship so that each item can have a relationship with many other items. I've set up the relationship according to the documentation (either two relationships, or one that is the inverse of itself is legal, i'm using the latter) and all works wonderfully until I go to delete an item that has a relationship with another item. If I choose the "Cascade" delete rule for the relationship, there's no crash and all functionality behaves as expected. If I'm using the "Nullify" delete rule though, the one I really want to use, I get a crash.

I'm assuming that even though I'm using a reflexive relationship, when deleting an Item, Core Data is going through and setting all of the references to that item in the other end of all relationships to null. Or do I have to reach in and do that manually? I'm thinking I shouldn't have to.

Or perhaps it's an "order of operations" issue with the FetchedResultsController?

I'm completely out of ideas on this one. Because of Apple's issues over the past couple of weeks, I haven't been able to get support from them.

I haven't posted code because there's a lot of it and most of it is template / boiler plate code anyway for this simple testing example I'm building.

Comment: Have you got a loop in the reflexive relationships?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, no loops using my relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

After more testing and logging, Core Data and the delete rule is not the problem. "Nullify" is working exactly as it should after an object is deleted, with any relationships that object may have. The problem is in the fetched results controller.

There must be a reference somewhere to that object that is not getting released. Other than when the relationship is created. It has to do with relationships because if there is no relationship, the object always deletes without a problem.

With an exception breakpoint on, it breaks in configureCell: when it tries to access an object of the fetchedResultsController at a specific index path.

NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

Without the exception breakpoint, I get the error:

CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  *** -[_PFBatchFaultingArray objectAtIndex:]: index (3) beyond bounds (3) with userInfo (null)

If I comment all of the code out of configureCell: the cells won't display properly, but I can't get it to crash. Everything works perfectly.

Sigh.